# Pre-loading Asset images in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I preload an asset image and use it in a Container widget? I tried the prechacheImage function but it's not working. whenever I start my application, its login screen background image flicks for a second, giving a bad experience.

Comment: Does the flickering happen in the release mode?

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean variable:

`bool _loading = true;`

Then in the `initState()` call the method what loads the image.

In the method where you load the image, when you are done, set the `_loading` false (`setState({ _loading = false});`)

In build method depending on the `_loading` show the user a `CircularProgressIndicator` or the actual screen:

```
_loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : MyScreen();
```